# Making a simple honeycomb launcher

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Working with a restaurant in an android tablet based menu app. If possible I would like to restrict access to just the menu app and browser. How would a I go about turning a normal dashboard app into a launcher replacement???

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `<activity>`:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When the user presses HOME again, they will get a chooser -- check the "make this the default" checkbox, then tap the entry for your app, and you're now the home screen.

Bear in mind, though, that:

- If you let users get to a browser, they will be able to download and run apps distributed publicly, plus click links that might lead to other apps on the device (e.g., YouTube, a PDF reader)
- If the user knows how to boot your device in safe mode, the firmware home screen will return; the only solution to this is to have your home screen be installed on the firmware of the device

There is a Home sample project in your SDK that demonstrates more of this.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a simple app that allows the user to start 2 different apps (the menu and the browser) using intents while never ending your main app. In that app/launcher app you can override the home/back button in such a way that it will not allow the user to quit that app/launcher. This means that once the app is started there is no way to stop it, except by turning the tablet off.

Comment: Fortunately, the specific techniques you are describing here do not work. You cannot "override the home" button in the way you describe, except by being a home screen.

Comment: @CommonsWare I took the idea from this app called MaplePaint where they overridden the home button in such a way that when you press on it a dialog comes out asking you if you want to save whatever you been working on. If that is possible why would my suggestion not work?

Comment: They are presumably overriding `onUserLeaveHint()`. They cannot block the HOME button behavior with that.